# pfile - client parameter file - starting an instance remotely

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I do not understand how we can start an Oracle instance remotely using a pfile.

If we ssh into the Oracle server and issue:

```
startup pfile='/path/to/pfile';`
```

the pfile is on the server side.

How can we actually startup a database remotely using a pfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure is described in the [Remote Startup of a Database Instance](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e27508/admin.htm#CACBGIBH) part of admin guide for BS2000/OSD (I can't find this part in the Linux docs...).

Essentially what you do is:

- Create an Oracle password file for your database if you haven't already done so
- Add a static registration for your instance in its listener
- Set the instance parameter `REMOTE_LOGIN_PASSWORDFILE` to `EXCLUSIVE`
- Restart the listener and the database.

Once you've done that and granted `sysdba` to a user, you can connect to the instance using `sqlplus` directly from another machine

```
c:\foobar> sqlplus /nolog
...
SQL> connect mat/mat@SOMETHING_REMOTE as sysdba
...
SQL> startup pfile='c:\foobar\init.ora'
```

That last command reads the pfile from the machine where `sqlplus` is running, not from a directory on the server.

**But** I'd generally say you probably shouldn't be doing this. Have your database all use spfiles on the server. Otherwise you never know how they were started.

Comment: The startup command is described in the [SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve045.htm#BACBIHBD) "Specifies the **client** parameter file to be used"

Comment: "Add a static registration for your instance in its listener" Maybe not all readers now how to do this, I think it would make sense to describe this in detail or add a reference.

Comment: @miracle173: the complete process is explained in the link in the first sentence, including how to set up the listener.

Comment: @Mat - when you mention restart the listener and the database , what would be the state of the database when you connect from remote as sysdba ? is the database/instance shutdown?   it doesn't make sense for me to connect from remote, and startup the database using pfile when the database is already open on the server side - please clarify

Comment: @Noob: the restart is necessary to make the config changes on the database and listener take effect (if you needed to change anything). Once that initial config is done, you can connect as sysdba remotely whatever the state of the db as long as the listener is up. But again: just don't do it.

Comment: @Mat do you mean once the restart is done, i can shutdown the database and still connect to the as sysdba to the listener even though that the database is close ?

Comment: Once the initial config is done, you can connect as sysdba whatever the state of the db. As long as the listener is up.